# Как сделать цикл склейки имени и числа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Есть два списка `prod_name = [ ]` и `price = [ ]`. В первый летит такое:

```
(item['title'],domen+item['href'])
```

В список прилетает такое значение: `Объявление «Playstation 4 Pro 1Tb (магазин, гарантия)» 3 фотографии`,
`ссылка`, а во вторую летит ценник - допустим, 1000. Хочу сделать цикл склейки `prod_name` и `price` по индексу, то есть, примерно так:

```
print(prod_name[conut]+price[count])
```

, где `count` - переменная со значением 0 по стандарту, но в последствии count увеличивается на 1 путём `count =+ 1`.

Comment: ссылку на сайт откуда парсите цены скинте, проще будет понять, что Вы хотите. Пока нифига не понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте список словарей. Каждый элемент словаря в списке - это какое-то объявление. А внутри словаря сделайте ключи и значения. Потом обращайтесь по ним. Примерно так:

```
lst_tovar = []
lst_img = ['foto1.jpg', 'foto2.jpg']
data_tovar = {
   'price': 100,
    'name': 'Playstation 4 Pro 1Tb (магазин, гарантия)',
    'lst_img': lst_img,
}
lst_tovar.append(data_tovar)
```

Ну можно, конечно на прямую добавлять - без `data_tovar`, но это на Ваше усмотрение.

Но по мне лучше так:

```
class Tovar():
    def __init__(self, price, name, lst_img_name):
        self.price = price
        self.name = name
        self.lst_img_name = lst_img_name
    def print_tovar_cena(self):
        print(f'Товар{self.name} \n Цена:{self.price}')


lst_objTovar = []
lst_img = ['foto1.jpg', 'foto2.jpg']
lst_objTovar.append(Tovar(price=100,
                      name='Playstation 4 Pro 1Tb (магазин, гарантия)',
                      lst_img_name=lst_img))

for tovar in lst_objTovar:
    tovar.print_tovar_cena()
```

А если хотите чтоб ID Вашего товара был:

```
for id, tovar in enumerate(lst_objTovar):
    print('id:', id)
    tovar.print_tovar_cena()
```

Answer (score 1):

В питоне "склейка" двух списков одинаковой длины делается через `zip`:

```
for prod_item, price_item in zip(prod_name, price):
    print(prod_item, price_item)
```

Если счётчик зачем-то всё же нужен ещё, то оборачиваете `zip` дополнительно в `enumerate`. А так параллельный перебор делается без счётчика.